# Incorporating assumptions on $f'$ and $f''$ in evaluating the Hessian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function with variables $s$ & $p$:
$$\text{Profit} = [a - b/f(s)]*p$$
where $f(s)$ is a function of $s$, such that $f'(s)>0$ and $f''(s)<0$ w.r.t. $s$.

I want to check whether Profit is concave or not using the Hessian.
But I don't know how to convey all the above steps to Mathematica.

Comment: To be honest, you may be jumping a bit too far ahead. Perhaps start by reading through [this tutorial on function definition in MMA](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html). Also you should only use parentheses `( ... )` to group operations and indicate precedence in your expressions. Brackets `[ ... ]` are reserved for function calls and braces `{ ... }` for lists.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: As a starting point, you can get the Hessian for your generic function $f(s)$ with `D[(a - b/f[s])*p, {{s, p}, 2}]`.

Comment: Thank you so much; comments are constructive to get started.